# Finding the last word in every sentence in a txt file

Tags: python

So I have a text file that has tweets in it.

I need to only print the last word in every line that is 8 or more characters and doesn't have # : or @ in the word.

Currently, I can find all the words in the text file that fulfils those requirements except only printing the last word in the sentence. So if a line that contains multiple words that fulfil the requirements I print all the words

This is how far I am currently

```
for line in open("tweets.txt"):
  line_strip = line.strip()
  for word in line_strip.split(): 
    if len(word) >=8 and "#" not in word and ":" not in word and "@" not in word:
      print(word)
```

The output is:

```
Candidates
remained
candidates
finished
Watching
couldn't
hangover
disappointing.
```

but should be:

```
remained
finished
couldn't
hangover
disappointing.
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Search backwards (use `reversed` on the input sequence), and stop as soon as you find something (by `break`ing the loop).

Answer (score 1):

```py
for line in open("tweets.txt"):
  line_strip = line.strip()
  words = [word for word in line_strip.split() if len(word) >=8 and "#" not in word and ":" not in word and "@" not in word] 
  if len(words)>0:
    print(words[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

`line_strip.split()` will give you a list, you can access the last element in this list with `your_list[-1]`, then apply your rules against this word in each line.